# how to retrieve all data from joining table using parent key

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server

I am working on a twitter like app. In this app, a user will have other user as followers and they can see followers posts. I have following tables:

[image]

According to the design, a user can have other users as followers (kind of like Unary relationship). I want to write a sql statement to retrieve all the followers post + my post (username, poststatus).

I tried different sql statement but doesn't return the correct data I need. For example like this:

```
    SELECT f.FirstName, f.LastName, up.PostStatus FROM UserPosts up 
    Inner join  (
          SELECT f.UserID,f.FollowerID, u.FirstName, u.LastName 
          from Followers f INNER JOIN Users u on  f.UserID = u.UserID 
          WHERE f.UserID = 1) as f 
   ON up.UserID = f.FollowerID 
   OR up.UserID=f.UserID
```

This query return all the followers posts but doesn't return the correct followers username , instead return the username for user 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select u.FirstName, u.LastName, up.PostStatus
from UserPosts as up
    inner join Users as u on u.UserID = up.UserID
where
    up.UserID = @UserID or
    exists (
        select *
        from Followers as f
        where f.FollowerID = up.UserID and f.UserID = @UserID
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

The following gives you
a) User 1 posts
b) Posts from anyone following User 1.

```
SELECT p.*
FROM posts p
WHERE userID = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT pf.*
FROM posts pf
JOIN followers f
ON pf.userID = f.followerID
WHERE f.userID = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Should the inner join in your sub query be pointing to F.userid or F.FollowerID?

Answer (score 0):

In your inner INNER JOIN, you state `WHERE f.UserID = 1`.  That appears to be restricting your results to just the first follower.

Answer (score 0):

I think like this

```
SELECT p.postStatus, p.firstname, p.lastname FROM Post p
INNER JOIN Follows f ON f.followerID=p.UserID AND f.UserID={user id you are selecting}
INNER JOIN Users u ON f.followeID=u.UserID
```